How can I set an icon for a Windows .exe from Linux?
I am trying to export a Godot project in a CI/CD pipeline on GitHub Actions. Godot doesn't offer functionality for adding icons to the exported Windows .exe out of the box and uses rcedit instead. rcedit does not run natively on Linux. Installing Wine in GitHub Actions or Windows with WSL for an icon seems quite silly...
Is there a native Linux program that can set Windows .exe icons?
There are other questions on this topic like this one or this one, but they are old and don't have satisfactory answers. Perhaps nowadays something like this exists?

you could try this, if you really only need to exchange the img: https://github.com/pkowal1982/godoticon . Sadly can't try it out myself right now.

@Bugfish I remember I tried that a few months back and couldn't get it to work, don't remember why anymore. In the end I gave up and am using Golang build scripts on GitHub actions with Windows runners now
